# How should I connect my ms sql database with my maven project

Tags: sql-server, spring, maven, database-connection

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="url" value="" />
          <property name="username" value="" />
          <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

[Mssql screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTBOn.jpg)

This is my code and the screen shot of my database .I want to use OrderInfo database. Can anyone please help me with what should be the url username and password should be?

Answer (score 0):

Try as :

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OrderInfo" />
     <property name="username" value="" />
     <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

More Info : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html

Also you can use as below too :

applicationContext-dataSource.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

jdbc.properties file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/OrderInfo
jdbc.username=
jdbc.password=
```

Comment: what will be the username pwd as I have login my database using window authentication not sql server authentication .I am getting this error "Access denied for user 'TANVI-HP\naresh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: looks like this user does not have required rights to the database.

Comment: I am working on my personal laptop and  created personal database .Why I dont have rights for the database